# Firebase Bigquery integration and Google Analytics part on it

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

So I will try to explain myself the best I can, and I would really appreciate any help!

May main Goal here is to export FireBase data to a DataStudio. I know how easy this is, just link FireBase to BigQuery and create a DataStudio with this data source. There's even already an awesome template for this.

But is not that simple, I work at an agency, this is a huge corporate client and their internal people work is a mess.

The problem here is: I can get "property" access to Firebase, and I have linked my Bigquery account to this project, but what I can't see is the whole app information in Bigquery.

What I see is the data from "crashalytics", "messaging", "performance" and predictions.
But can't seem to find the "normal info" off the app, the events, conversions, audiences, etc...

This is where I can't understand some things that I would like you to help me with, I have some theories.

In the configuration of bigquery integration on firebase I have every switch marked as "On" but one, the analytics one. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k9Q1.png)

Now here is where all my questions come:
- ¿Do I need this switch to be on so I can visualize, for example Events or users information on Bigquery?

If so, what is the realtion between Firebase and Google Analytics?:
 - ¿Is it necesary to have a Google Analytics account integrated with the Firebase project in order for bigquery to extract the data and show it?
 - ¿Can I extract directly through firebase the data without Google analytics?

And an extra one: If I remove the Google Analytics account from my Firebase project, and add a new one, ¿Would the new Google Analytics also have the data so I can extract it with Bigquery and build my panel?

The biggest problem here is that this Firebase account was created long ago, and the client haves no idea what Google Analytics account is Linked to the Firebase project, they know nobody with acces to it, and they say "I'ts an old analytics, we only need Firebase information to show on datastudio" but I'm starting to feel this is not possible without this Google Analytics acces.

Pleaaase some help with this.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you read this page https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, if anybody comes to this problem, the problem was I needed permision to the analytics web + app created from firebase.